# Hybrid Card-Dice Game: How do I protect it?

Tags: card, dice, game, mechanics

I have a hybrid card-dice game.  I know I have to copyright the rules text, the card text, and any graphic artwork on the card face and/or card back; trademark the name and logo of the game, any logos, any character likenesses in the artwork itself, any slogans (I'm creator-manufacturer so far and see myself having to market this myself, so yeah slogans and ad campaigns -- but waaaaay far future); and I know I have to patent both the card and the game mechanics.  Thing is, How do I patent the game mechanics if I've already outlined them in the rule book? Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: There have been several other very similar questions. You might search within Ask Patents.

Comment: Have you yet publicly disclosed the rule book?

Answer (score 1):

The USPTO is still issuing patents for card games and board games by the flow has slowed over the last few years. I filed a [patent application](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20110018199A1) for a board game for a client and it was essentially rejected as being abstract as a "methods of organizing human activity”. This is a phrase plucked out of a SCOTUS case ([Bilski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilski_v._Kappos)) that, [in the opinion of many](https://www.ipwatchdog.com/2015/03/10/methods-of-organizing-human-activities/id=55607/), is taken out of context to go crazy rejecting things. A later SCOTUS case ([Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International)) has added to the wholesale rejections and invalidation of things that would not be considered abstract by anyone 20 years ago.

[Criss cross poker casino card game with middle bet and five card bonus bet US 9564016](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9564016B2) is an example of a recent patent on a game involving cards and dice. You can look up more at the USPTO patent [search](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html) with a search string [CPC/"A63F1/00" AND DIE AND CARD].

You can look at these as a start in searching the novelty of your ideas. I'm sure you know that you do not need a patent to market a product. I think most games like this are protected reasonably well by trademark, but that is not my field.

Answer (score 0):

Many countries only grant patents for inventions that solve technical problems. Gameplay or game mechanics of a card game do not solve a technical problem, so you cannot get a patent for those. In the European Patent Convention this is explicitly laid down in [Art. 52.c](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/ar52.html):

> (2) The following in particular *shall not be regarded as inventions* within the meaning of paragraph 1:
> [...]
> (c) schemes, rules and methods for performing mental acts, *playing games* or doing business, and programs for computers;

Patenting it in the US perhaps is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As The Europeist notes, patents for games isn't possible in many countries. I do believe it is possible to get a game patent in the US. However getting patents is not easy or cheap. The best way, by far, is to employ a patent attorney or agent with experience in game patents. It is possible to file and obtain a patent without professional help, but it is very likely such a patent will provide weak protection and is much less likely to actually get granted.

Just to note, you certainly don't need to obtain a patent to market your game. The patent just provides some protection from someone marketing the same or a similar game.

Comment: Until a few years ago the USPTO was issuing many patents for board games and so-called proprietary card games, many of which involved  novel betting rules. This is now much harder.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite This is well beyond my area of expertise. I’d welcome a better answer from you. Mostly I was trying to tell the OP that a patent isn’t required to sell the game. I may delete my answer, I haven’t decided yet.